# Custom UITableViewCell always black unless set to anything but clear

Tags: iphone

My custom UITableViewCells always have a black background unless I set the background of the UITableView to clear.

However I want to set the background colour to another colour and as soon as I do the cells turn black (even though the background of the control does change)

Comment: How are you setting the background color? In Interface Builder, or code?

Comment: In code tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: Does part of your custom TableViewCell involve a transparent image? Have you set the `opaque` property for that image to `NO` either programmatically or in Interface Builder?

Comment: Can you post an example of your viewWillAppear (or equiv) where you configure your table view, and your cellForRowAtIndexPath methods?